# plone.registry - How do I capture a change in registry when IRecordModifiedEvent is fired?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I'm trying to replicate an example of detecting the change in registry when IRecordModified is supposed to be fired.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.registry#registry-events

I try to adapt this to what I am doing, but a print statement I placed isn't firing.

In my registry.xml

```
<registry>
    <records interface="my.product.utils.db_settings.IDBSettings">
</registry>
```

In my events.py

```
from my.product.utils.db_settings import IDBSettings

@adapter(IDBSettings, IRecordModifiedEvent)
def detectDBSettingsChange(settings, event):
    print "detectDBSettingsChange"
```

In the module db_settings.py, which contain the control panel , I have:
    from plone.app.registry.browser import controlpanel

```
class IDBSettings(Interface):
    db_string = schema.TextLine(title=u"Database String",
                                description=u"String for database connection",
                                default=u"Some value"
        )

class DBSettingsEditForm(controlpanel.RegistryEditForm):
    schema = IDBSettings
    label = u"Database settings"
    description = u"String setup"

    def updateFields(self):
        super(DBSettingsEditForm, self).updateFields()


    def updateWidgets(self):
        super(DBSettingsEditForm, self).updateWidgets()

class DBSettingsControlPanel(controlpanel.ControlPanelFormWrapper):
    form = DBSettingsEditForm
```

In my configure.zcml in utils:

```
<include package="plone.app.registry" />
<browser:page
         name="database-settings"
         for="Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.IPloneSiteRoot"
         class=".db_settings.DBSettingsControlPanel"
         permission="cmf.ManagePortal"
         />
```

When I go into the control panel, change the value, and then save, detectDBSettingsChange doesn't seem to work as the print statement is ignored.  Am I working with the wrong event to capture the change in my registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a subscriber and register it like this in your configure.zcml file:

```xml
<configure xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope">

  <subscriber
      for="plone.registry.interfaces.IRecordModifiedEvent"
      handler="your.package.your_subscriber"
      />

</configure>
```

Check the [collective.fingerpointing](https://github.com/collective/collective.fingerpointing) package for [a working example](https://github.com/collective/collective.fingerpointing/blob/master/src/collective/fingerpointing/subscribers/registry_logger.py) of this.

Comment: Hi, I apologize for my late response.   Thank you. This is what I was looking for.  I forgot to add that and this solved my problem.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a subscriber like described in the [docs](http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/components/events.html#registering-an-event-handler). I'm not sure that the adapter in your events.py is sufficient. Perhaps you can use provideHandler Method like described in [plone.registry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.registry#registry-events)

Comment: Hi, I apologize for my late response.   Thank you. That's what I was looking for.  I forgot the step for adding the subscriber to the configure.zcml.